# Docker jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion doesn't generate a proper certificate

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, digital-ocean, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

I'm following a tutorial to deploy `Wordpress` using `Docker` on a `Ubuntu` server. The tutorial is in this [website](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/docker-wordpress-production-deployment/?unapproved=22388&moderation-hash=ee33649eac033fa2fc25727150ab6efe#step-7.-run-the-nginx-reverse-proxy).

It's important to mention that I already have two subdomains at this point, one for the Wordpress site and another for the phpMyAdmin site.

However the `letsencrypt` certificates seem to not be generated properly. I can access the website via http, but not https, and when I look at the certificate it doesn't look correct. In fact it doesn't seem to have one for my website.

[image: Screenshoot of how the "cert" looks in the browser]

To make everything easier I created a script to run all the steps fast:

```
#!/bin/bash

web_dir=/srv/www
myusername=root
domain_name=subdomain.domain.com
website_folder=/srv/www/$domain_name

nginx_proxy_repo=https://github.com/kassambara/nginx-multiple-https-websites-on-one-server
nginx_folder=/srv/www/nginx-multiple-https-websites-on-one-server/nginx-proxy
final_nginx_folder=/srv/www/nginx-proxy

echo ---INSTALL REQUIRED COMPONENTS----
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce docker-compose git
sudo systemctl status docker

echo ---CREATE AND GIVE PERMISSIONS TO WEBSITES DIR----
sudo mkdir -p $web_dir
# 2. set your user as the owner
sudo chown -R $myusername $web_dir
# 3. set the web server as the group owner
sudo chgrp -R www-data $web_dir
# 4. 755 permissions for everything
sudo chmod -R 755 $web_dir
# 5. New files and folders inherit 
# group ownership from the parent folder
chmod g+s $web_dir

echo ---INSTALL NGINX PROXY----
git clone $nginx_proxy_repo $web_dir
rm -rf $web_dir/nginx-proxy/nginx.tmpl
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/master/nginx.tmpl > $web_dir/nginx-proxy/nginx.tmpl
cd $web_dir
rm -rf your-website-one.com your-website-two.com README.Rmd .gitignore .Rbuildignore .git README.md

echo ---INSTALL WORDPRESS----
cd $web_dir
git clone https://github.com/kassambara/wordpress-docker-compose $domain_name

echo ---CONFIGURE DOCKER COMPOSE FOR ONLINEHOST----
cd $website_folder
mv docker-compose-onlinehost.yml docker-compose.yml

echo ---FINAL TOUCHES----
cd $website_folder
vi ./setup-onlinehost.sh
chmod +x setup-onlinehost.sh && ./setup-onlinehost.sh
vi .env
vi docker-compose.yml

cd $final_nginx_folder
docker network create nginx-proxy
docker-compose up -d

cd $final_nginx_folder
cd vhost.d
echo "client_max_body_size 64M;" > $domain_name

cd $website_folder
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f wp-auto-config.yml run --rm wp-auto-config
```

When the time comes I setup the `setup-onlinehost.sh` like this:

```
project_name="wordpress"
user_name="wordpress"
pass_word="wordpress"
email="mail@gmail.com"
website_title="My Blog"
website_url="https://subdomain.domain.com"
phmyadmin_url="sqlsubdomain.domain.com"
env_file=".env"
compose_file="docker-compose.yml"
```

Then I remove the `redirectnonwww` container from the `docker-compose.yml` file since I don't want the redirect `non-www` to `www` behavior.

Then after everything is completed, I can access the websites over `http` but not over `https`. When I try to access it over `https` I receive a message about `This connection is not private` and the certificate seems to be wrong at this point.

Also If I let continue my browser to visit the website I got to the `Nginx 500 Internal Server Error`.

If I look into the contents of `nginx-proxy/certs` I see listed the following items:

```
certs (folder)
   default.crt  
   default.key  
   dhparam.pem  
   subdomain.domain.com (empty folder) 
   sqlsubdomain.domain.com (empty folder)
conf.d (folder)
docker-compose.yml
html  
nginx.tmpl  
vhost.d (folder)
   subdomain.domain.com (file)
```

The contents of `vhost.d/subdomain.domain.com` are:

```
## Start of configuration add by letsencrypt container
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
    auth_request off;
    allow all;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    break;
}
## End of configuration add by letsencrypt container
client_max_body_size 64M;
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I should be doing something else that is not listed on the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be the number of times I had requested a certificate for those specific domains. I tried the deploy multiple times to figure out how to do it properly for the deployment server and also to write a proper version of the script, that I requested many times a certificate for two specific domains.

The issue was resolved after I tried a different domain and subdomain.